# NameError undefined local variable or method `current_period_end'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am try to save Stripes `current_period_end` attribute to the Subscription table, however I am getting a NameError for the line `self.cancellation_date = current_period_end`

Subscription.rb:

```
  attr_accessor :stripe_card_token, :paypal_payment_token, :cancellation_date

 def save_with_stripe_payment
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
    self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
    self.cancellation_date = current_period_end
    save!
  rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
    logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
    errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
    false
  end
```

Comment: What makes you think `current_period_end` should be defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASAIK current_period_end should be a property of a subscription object. So it might be something like

```
customer.subscription.current_period_end
```

### EDIT

After looking at Stripe API docs (https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#customer_object) regarding the customer object, I relized that subscriptions is in fact an array of subscription object. So you'd need in fact to figure which subscription to get but her's a sample that would work

```
customer.subscriptions.first.current_period_end
```

Which would take the first subscription and check it. In fact, you might probably want to fetch the latest one (subscriptions.last)

Comment: I tried that prior to posting here, which is why I removed `customer.subscription`. That was giving me a NoMethodError `undefined method subscription`. Which is why I removed it. Stripe's API with current_period_end is here https://stripe.com/docs/api#subscription_object. Even when I user `customer.id.current_period_end` I get a `undefined method for current_period_end`. The form works when I remove the line of course.

Comment: That makes sense. I just tested it and it works. Thanks!